# What hardware / software do I need to port my C++/wxWidgets app to the MAC?

Tags: c++, macos, wxwidgets, porting, requirements

I have a C++/wxWidgets codebase and I'm starting to think about porting it across to Linux and the Mac OS X.

What hardware / software do I need (or is recommended) to code on the Mac platform? Currently I use Visual Studio to develop in and Innosetup to do my packaging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Mac development, the simplest and easiest solution is to use Xcode on Mac OS X.

You might be able to virtualize that on your Windows box, or install it as second OS depending on your hardware, but the path of least resistance is to develop with an actual Mac in front of you.

Comment: "You might be able to virtualize that on your Windows box" - not if you care about the licensing terms. Mac OS X is only licensed for use on Apple-branded hardware.

Comment: I hadn't realised that Sherm. Do you have a citation?

Comment: Section 2A of the license, found here: http://store.apple.com/Catalog/US/Images/MacOSX.htm

Comment: Yes, though it is forbidden by the license on software you already paid for, it is possible to virtualize or install Mac OS X on *some* non-Apple hardware. You can also legitimately virtualize Mac OS X Server under the current license.

Comment: I didn't say it was impossible, I said it wasn't allowed by the license. And yes, the license for Mac OS X Server allows you to run it in a VM - **if** the VM host is running on Apple hardware.

Answer (score 4):

The Mac equivalent of Visual Studio is Xcode (assuming you have a Mac :-), which includes the Mac port of gcc.

http://developer.apple.com/xcode/

Answer (score 1):

You can use [IMCROSS](http://www.sandroid.org/imcross) to set up an environment for targeting Windows and MacOS X from Linux.